# Laravel Eloquent - Encrypting/Decrypt Data on call

Tags: encryption, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I can use `Crypt` to encrypt/decrypt my data. I want to encrypt some information in my db (such as the name, email, phone number to name a few).

Assuming that I want EVERYTHING to be encrypted, I want to be able to do this in the background by itself, which I can perform by overwriting the `create` and `save` functions:

```
// For instance, the save() function could become
public function save(array $options = array())
{
    foreach ($this->attributes as $key => $value)
    {
        if (isset($value)) $this->attributes[$key] = Crypt::encrypt($value);
    }
    return parent::save($options);
}
```

Now, I want the decryption to be performed the same way, so that when I say `User::find($id)`, the returned `$user` is already decrypted. Also other functions such as `firstOrFail()` `get()` `first()` and all to work as well.

I also would like this functionality to be extended when I use relationships (so `User::with('someOtherTable')->find($id)` also work).

Would this be possible? If this is not possible, I am thinking of creating a helper function `decyrpt()`

```
function decrypt($array)
{
    if (!is_array($array)) return Crypt::decrypt($array);

    $result = [];

    foreach($array as $key => $value) $result[$key] = decrypt($value);

    return $result;
}
```

And pass all my results through this first, and then start using them, but it would be nicer if Laravel would provide this, or if there was a "Laravel Way" of doing this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to encrypt *everything*. For example, you never want to encrypt the primary key; that doesn't even make sense. Likewise you probably don't want to encrypt the date fields; you'll lose the ability to perform any sort of SQL query on them.

With that in mind, you can try something like this:

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    protected $encrypt = [];

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->encrypt))
        {
            $value = Crypt::encrypt($value);
        }

        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }

    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->encrypt))
        {
            return Crypt::decrypt($this->attributes[$key]);
        }

        return parent::getAttribute($key);
    }

    public function attributesToArray()
    {
        $attributes = parent::attributesToArray();

        foreach ($attributes as $key => $value)
        {
            if (in_array($key, $this->encrypt))
            {
                $attributes[$key] = Crypt::decrypt($value);
            }
        }

        return $attributes;
    }

}
```

then have all you models extend this one, and set the `$encrypt` property to whatever columns you want encrypted for that particular model.

---

**P.S.** If you want to use Eloquent's accessor functionality, you'll have to play with this a bit more.

Comment: This doesn't work. When for instance, I use `User::find(1)`, the only `$key` being called in `getAttribute()` is the `id` and `pivot`

Comment: I do! I use `return Response::json(User::find($id))` as an example, and the `getAttribute` is never called. If I do `User::find($id)->name`, then yes it does get called. But I return this from the API, so I need the JSON to work? Even `User::find($id)->toJson()` doesn't call it

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you! One small comment, I think you need to type `Crypt::decrypt($this->attributes[$key]);` as oppose to `Crypt::decrypt($this->attributes($key));` since `$this->attributes` is an array and not a function.

Comment: is there any other work around if I use Query Builder then Eloquent ?

Answer (score 1):

It's worth mentioning [Elocrypt](https://github.com/dtisgodsson) library for Laravel 4. It's a more elaborate solution that works the same way. If you're using Laravel 5 use this one instead: [Elocrypt 5](https://github.com/delatbabel/elocryptfive).

Comment: https://github.com/austinheap/laravel-database-encryption looks good too.