# How to perform better search in Laravel when the database columns value are encrypted?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, encryption, eloquent

Recently I come across this request: the **columns** values must be encrypted, even programmers *(means the programmers for this project)* also cannot access the database.

What I can think of is to encrypt all the columns data, which I found [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687597/laravel-eloquent-encrypting-decrypt-data-on-call). But then another issue comes, if I want to perform search, and columns are encrypted, which mean I cannot use `WHERE` to filter the result, instead, I have to retrieve all the records from the table, then only filter by PHP script. I just couldn't imagine if there are 10mil records...

Anyone of you facing this kind of problem? Can suggest any solutions here.

Thanks

Comment: You can encrypt the search value for "equals" comparison. You cannot do LIKE or greater/less-than, or BETWEEN searches.

Comment: @JimGarrison when come to search, definitely need `LIKE`, is there any suggestion aside from encrypt the column value? The main purpose of doing this is don't let the programmers _(which is me and the team)_ to see the data in the database

Comment: @JsLim No, unless you're prepared to implement support for [homomorphic encryption](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dwu4/fhe.html) in your favorite database management system. If you need to search it, don't encrypt it. If you need to encrypt it, being able to search it will leak facts about the data through side-channels, so don't do that.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski Omg.. homomorphic encryption so complicated, I'm not going to implement that. Thanks for advice anyway